# Drawer - arrangement of icons

Tags: samsung-touchwiz, app-drawer

Why does the arrangement of app icons change (to alphabetical order), and why do folders get deleted, on every update of the Android version?

Follow up Qs:
1. How can I prevent this from happening?
2. Is there a way to restore the previous arrangement, after the update (if I did not follow your answer to Question 1) or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: Are you talking about the app drawer or the home screen? They're different, you know. The app drawer is just a list of your apps. The home screen allows you to arrange icons (including putting them in folders) and widgets.

Comment: I was talking about the drawer. We can customize the arrangements on both the app drawer and the home screen.

Comment: Not my phone. What device/carrier?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note. Vodafone. Maybe its the IceCreamS Launcher's feature or the Samsung Touchwiz Launcher's feature. Am unsure.

Comment: Only 1 Launcher can be active on a phone right? How do you know which Launcher is currently active? The android one or the carrier one?

Comment: It must be TouchWiz. In the default Android app drawer you can't arrange the icons.

Comment: If I change my arrangement on the home screen/drawer, where does the launcher store that setting? in the Launcher's app cache right? But Touchwiz's cache shows 0 bytes.